# Finding length contraction of a moving object in a moving frame of reference both moving relative to a stationary frame

Tags: special-relativity, velocity, time-dilation

I'll start with an example:
Suppose a spaceship was moving towards the Earth and ejected a weather satellite away from the Earth. The spaceship's speed was 0.8c and the satellite was ejected at 0.2c, both velocities given relative to an observer stationary on the Earth.
A person in the spaceship observes the width of the upper atmosphere to be 7.1km. What would be the length observed through the satellite's frame?

Why would it be incorrect to use relativistic addition of velocities to determine the velocity of the satellite through the spaceship's reference frame and then use that to determine the length contraction observed by the satellite?

The correct solution is first to determine the proper length then use that to determine the contracted length

Comment: If you do it the right way you should get the same result, but you have to take in account that the 7.1 km move relative to the spaceship with -0,8c

Answer (score 2):

This spacetime diagram might help. (Time runs upwards.)

It might be helpful to interpret the physics problem trigonometrically, using rapidities (the Minkowski-angles). You can reason like you would with Euclidean geometry *(cosine = adjacent/hypotenuse, etc)*, but you would use hyperbolic trig functions.

For your problem,
you are essentially given

- the rapidities $\theta={\rm arctanh}(8/10)$ and $\phi={\rm arctanh}({\rm abs}(-2)/10)$ 
  [so the gamma-factors are $\cosh\theta$ and $\cosh\phi$, respectively]
- the "width of the atmosphere according to the ship" $L_{ship}=24 {\rm\ \mu s\cdot c} \approx 7.2 {\rm\ km}$ *(nudged from 7.1 km to simplify the arithmetic)*,
  which is the hypotenuse of a Minkowski-right-triangle whose base is the proper-length $L_0$ of the atmosphere [the distance between the "parallel worldlines of the ground and top-of-atmosphere" along the spacelike-direction Minkowski-perpendicular to the worldlines].

and you seek

- the "width of the atmosphere according to the satellite" $L_{sat}$,
  which is the hypotenuse of the lower triangle in the diagram.

Strategies for the answer:

- Computing the relative-velocity $\tanh(\phi+\theta)$ isn't immediately helpful since you would probably need to work with a Minkowski-right-triangle with that rapidity $\phi+\theta$. Since it's not given, you'd have to construct one.
- As you say, it is better to calculate the common base $L_0$ from $24=L_0/\cosh\theta$, then use that to find the hypotenuse $L_0/\cosh\phi$.
  With your given speeds, you'll find that $L_0=40{\rm\ \mu s\cdot c}$.

[image: robphy-spacetime-trig]

Comment: I'm in year 12 (high school maths/physics doesn't cover multi-dimensional applications of special rel)... Thank you nonetheless!

Comment: @HamadanMahmood This is a relativity problem in 1-D space. A spacetime diagram is essentially a PHY 101 position-vs-time diagram (where the convention in relativity is to have t run upwards instead of rightwards). What is possibly unfamiliar is extracting information from the diagram using the "geometry of spacetime", which was formulated by Minkowski 1907 to better explain the formulas for "velocity addition", "length contraction", etc.. and reveal what underlies Einstein's Special Relativity.